# To show a function is differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $ f, g : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}^m$ . Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $p ∈ R$ , that $f (p) = 0$ and that $g$ is continuous at $p$ .

Let $h(x) = f (x) g(x)$ (again we use the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^m$ ).
Show that $h$ is differentiable at $p$ and that the directional derivative of $h$ at $p$ along $v$ is given
by $ g(p).(Df (p)(v))$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts/ideas?

Comment: Ya.According to my thoughts ,  The inner product will be just integration of product of two functions. NOw we know that the function f is diff. at p but then i dont know what to do with g !

Comment: As demonstrated in the answer below, think back to how one defines the derivative of $h$ (and that of $f$) and then fiddle around with it.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, $p=0$.
$$f(v)g(v)-f(0)g(0) = (f(v) - f(0))g(v) + f(0)(g(v)-g(0))$$
Now use $f(0)=0$ and $f(v) -f(0) = df(0)v +o(||v||)$, the continuity of $g$ and the definition of differentiability.

Comment: you're method is right, but please be more precise! Add the definition (with the limit) and show the steps :-)

Comment: whatever.. That was just my opinion

Comment: BUt $f(p)= and not F(0)$ ? Am I missing something ? Can you elaborate a little more ?

Comment: I deliberately set $p=0$. Otherwise you need to look at $f(p+v)$ instead of $f(v)$ which is just a bit more inconvenient notationwise. I adjusted my text accordingly.

Comment: By Definition of differentiability you mean the limit definition is it ? and continuity which definition ?

Comment: The question is what happens when $v \rightarrow 0$. The second product term on the right hand side (with $f(0)$ in front of it) can be ignored, since $f(0)= 0$. For the first one you need to show it converges to the desired result when $v\rightarrow 0$. The easiest way to treat the first one is to use the fact that the product of continuous functions is continuous and (for the $o(||v||)$ term) that $ g$ as continous function is bounded.